# How to chose both Java and Groovy?

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy

When you create a Spring Boot app via the Spring Initializr (which is the only way I know), you have to chose either Java or Groovy. This seems odd, as Groovy is just a superset of Java.

Anyway, I want to use both!

How does one have both Java and Groovy, like you can do seamlessly with Grails?

Comment: Does this answer to your question https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-java-applications

Comment: Statememts that groovy is a superset of java are inaccurate https://stackoverflow.com/q/4272068/217324

Comment: if you pick groovy, java is available out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick Groovy and then put your `.java` files inside the Groovy source root; the
Groovy compiler falls back to the Java compiler for those files. Doing
it this way, you make sure, that dependencies are handled correctly (if
you put them inside the Java source root, one of the source roots will
be compiled first and you will have a hard time handling dependencies
properly).

Comment: I tried selecting groovy, but unfortunately, VSCode cant run it with F5 (says "Cannot find a class with the main method" or from boot dashboard, says: No main class is found.