# Regarding Hosting Java application without dedicated Server

Tags: java, php, mysql, web-services, security

my question is that......

I want to host my content management system without java dedicated server,Because of high Cost of java server.And what framework is beneficial for me to make content management system in java......

Help please,Thank you from my side.

Comment: The second part of the question is a request to find a provider for you which is off topic for this site. And the first one is difficult to answer now and will also lead to opinion-based answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try amazon web services for hosting:
[AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/)

Grails is built on groovy and provides you with features like scaffolding. Groovy is an extension of java and relatively easy and fun to use. See these official sites for groovy and grails and this SO post for more info:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959165/groovy-superset-of-java)
[Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/)
[Grails](https://grails.org/)

Ultimately not a definite answer, but rather just some suggestions